# Color picker set individual attribute in JQuery each

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three buttons on a page I've set up as an array. I'm using $.each to iterate through them and inside that is the color picker function. I'm trying to have only the (last) clicked button change background color, but right now, if I click all 3 before using the color picker, they all change color. I need the button last clicked only to change color. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uBAMk/)

```
var test1 = $('#test1');
var test2 = $('#test2');
var test3 = $('#test3');
var elements = [test1, test2, test3]

 $.each(elements, function(i) {
   function handler() {
      $('#color').change(function(){
        $(elements[i]).unbind('click', handler);
        elements[i].css('background-color', this.value);
      });
   }

   $(elements[i]).bind('click', handler)

 });
```

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net) of what you currently have? Side note: if you are already using jQuery, no need for `document.getElementById`

Comment: Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uBAMk/)

Comment: Any reason why you need to bind a `click` for each button if you only need to bind a click event to the last button?

Comment: I'm fairly new to this so that is a mistake on my part. I'll take out the bind but I'm still not sure how to get it to do what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems overly complex. A simpler solution might be this:

1. Add click handlers to the buttons. When a button is clicked, add an "active" class to that button and remove from others.
2. Bind a change handler to the color picker. When that happens, change the background color of the active button:

I'm also going to assume you can give a class of `colorButton` to the buttons:

```
$('.colorButton').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.colorButton').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})

$('#color').change(function() {
    $('.colorButton.active').css('background-color', this.value);
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wBsab/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you bind the click event with the color change?

```
$('.buttons_that_change_color_on_click').bind('click', function(){

    this.style.backgroundcolor = the_value_you_want;

});
```